# Java error running Docear on Mint

Tags: java

I have installed Docear on Mint following the xenial instructions given here:
https://howto-ubuntunew.blogspot.com/2017/02/how-to-install-docear-12-on-ubuntu-1604.html

Running $ docear 
gives me these error messages:

```
Knopflerfish OSGi framework, version 4.1.10
Copyright 2003-2009 Knopflerfish. All Rights Reserved.

See http://www.knopflerfish.org for more information.
Loading xargs file /usr/share/docear/props.xargs
Loading xargs file /usr/share/docear/init.xargs
Installed and started: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/core/org.freeplane.core (id#1)
User properties not found, new file created
Installed: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.freeplane.plugin.bugreport (id#2)
Installed: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.freeplane.plugin.openmaps (id#3)
Installed: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.freeplane.plugin.svg (id#4)
Installed: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.freeplane.plugin.latex (id#5)
Installed: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.freeplane.plugin.workspace (id#6)
Installed: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.docear.plugin.core (id#7)
Installed: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.freeplane.plugin.formula (id#8)
Installed: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.docear.plugin.bibtex (id#9)
Installed: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.freeplane.plugin.script (id#10)
Installed: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.docear.plugin.services (id#11)
Installed: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.docear.plugin.pdfutilities (id#12)
Started: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.freeplane.plugin.bugreport (id#2)
Started: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.freeplane.plugin.openmaps (id#3)
Started: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.freeplane.plugin.svg (id#4)
Started: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.freeplane.plugin.latex (id#5)
Started: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.freeplane.plugin.workspace (id#6)
Started: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.docear.plugin.core (id#7)
Started: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.freeplane.plugin.formula (id#8)
Started: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.docear.plugin.bibtex (id#9)
Started: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.freeplane.plugin.script (id#10)
Started: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.docear.plugin.services (id#11)
Started: reference:file:/usr/share/docear/plugins/org.docear.plugin.pdfutilities (id#12)
Jun 19, 2018 2:03:03 AM org.freeplane.core.util.LogUtils info
INFO: freeplane_version = 1.3.2 alpha; freeplane_xml_version = freeplane 1.3.0
git revision = 547e9af_Anwender_2015-08-021946550200
java_version = 9-internal; os_name = Linux; os_version = 4.4.0-122-generic
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007efcb1f1a009, pid=14059, tid=14079
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/cjpoor/hs_err_pid14059.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
/usr/bin/docear: line 221: 14059 Aborted                 "${JAVACMD}" -Xmx512m "-Dorg.freeplane.param1=$1" "-Dorg.freeplane.param2=$2" "-Dorg.freeplane.param3=$3" "-Dorg.freeplane.param4=$4" "-Dorg.knopflerfish.framework.bundlestorage=memory" "-Dorg.freeplane.globalresourcedir=${freedir}/resources" "-Dorg.knopflerfish.gosg.jars=reference:file:${freedir}/core/" $defines $xdockname -jar "${freedir}/framework.jar" -xargs "${freedir}/props.xargs" -xargs "${freedir}/init.xargs"
```

I am running

```
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="18.1 (Serena)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 18.1"
VERSION_CODENAME=serena
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Linux Mint 19 with oracle-java-10 installed and don't run. I installed oracle-java-8 with ppa by webupd8 (http://webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) and deleted java 10 and now it's running very well. 
Good Luck!